# sqlite - How to select rows based on probability via integer value?

Tags: python, sqlite, probability

In my database, I have a list of bands along with a popularity column, which is incremented or decremented when a user, on a webpage, presses a like or dislike button respectively. I want to select bands based on this popularity column. The probability that a band is selected depends on this popularity column, which is an integer value, and not a decimal value like 0.3, 0.1, which should make sense if one is working with probability, but in my case, I don't think it's possible. Example of my table:

```
Bands        probability
Led Zeppelin    79
Megadeth         4
Queen           37
Aerosmith       20
Guns N Roses   103
```

Based on this, Guns N' Roses should have a highest chance of being selected, while Megadeth has the lowest chance of being selected, while other bands also each have their own chances of being selected. I'll be selecting 10 bands from a list of 2000.

Comment: "I don't think it's possible" Why? Are you open to using the `numpy` library? This is very possible.

Comment: Although, I have no idea at all how I would implement it solely in `sql`, I'd have to select the probabilities in `python` first and it might not actually be massively efficient.

Comment: @roganjosh I'm a beginner programmer. Should I try to learn numpy or will it be too difficult for someone at my level?

Comment: The reason I asked was more because it adds another dependency and sometimes that's not possible on servers etc.

Comment: I'm actually going to leave this question for a bit before formulating an answer because my approach is going to deviate so far from just `sqlite3` and, by answering, others will be less likely to open the question at all (and I think there's a much better alternative, I just don't know it). The first step for the probabilities is that you just need to "normalize" those counts. Nice question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, compute the [cumulative probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for each band (the sort order is arbitrary; you could just as well use some ID):

```sql
SELECT Band, 
       CAST((SELECT sum(probability)
             FROM Bands AS b2
             WHERE b2.Band <= Bands.Band
            ) AS FLOAT) /
       (SELECT sum(probability) FROM Bands)
       AS CumProb
FROM Bands
ORDER BY Band;
```

```sql
Band             CumProb       
---------------  ---------------
Aerosmith        0.0823045267489
Guns N Roses     0.5061728395061
Led Zeppelin     0.8312757201646
Megadeth         0.8477366255144
Queen            1.0
```

(As long as SQLite has not yet window functions, doing the summing in Python would be more efficient. But for 2000 rows, this does not really matter.)

Then use a random number between 0 and 1 to look up one of the rows (the first one that is equal or larger):

```sql
WITH CPBands(Band, CumProb) AS (
  SELECT Band, 
         CAST((SELECT sum(probability)
               FROM Bands AS b2
               WHERE b2.Band <= Bands.Band
              ) AS FLOAT) /
         (SELECT sum(probability) FROM Bands)
  FROM Bands
)
SELECT Band
FROM CPBands
WHERE CumProb >= ?
ORDER BY CumProb ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Repeat as often as needed, ignoring duplicates.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in flask in application.py?
Currently, I'm using the following query to select bands:
rows = db.execute("SELECT band FROM :genre ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 10", genre=genre)
Where genre is a table name. The selected bands should be assigned to the variable rows.
How can I replicate your answer in this db.execute statement?

Comment: The query returns one row. Write a loop in Python.

Comment: When I try to run this statement in the function db. execute, it gives me the following error:
RuntimeError: too many statements at once
Could you suggest an alternative function that would run your sql queries in a single line and store the result in a variable?

Comment: You have accidentally put an additional semicolon somewhere into the statement.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question and problem correctly you want to select the 10 bands that have the highest popularity/probability values right?

in SQL you may be able to do:

Select * FROM table_name ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 10

This selects all columns in your table, sorts the by popularity in descending order (largest to smallest), and stops after the first 10 entries.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The OP is not asking how to get the values from their probability table, they want to get band names in a probability distribution, based on those values.

Comment: right but the probabilities are based off the popularities, so you can probably just skip the probability calculation and go by popularity unless there is extra calculations done. if so then the probability should be calculated out of the DB, then stored in the DB and used in the same manner as above to query the results.

Comment: Just re read the question, and now i understand better. its not a ranking and pick top 10. its generate random numbers to decide wich 10 to use....

Comment: That is very far removed from how probability works. You can't just reorder a list and take the top 10 if you want a random sample.

Comment: Now that you understand the question, do you think it can be done in SQL? My knowledge isn't strong enough to make a pure-SQL answer, I would have to make the decision externally in Python.

Comment: I can't think of how to do it in SQL (my knowledge of it isn't strong enough), and looking at the size of the table OP is using I would probably just implement a solution in python or some other language, 2000 entries is no big deal to query out of the DB.